# Outlook web-addin open external application with registered scheme

Tags: outlook-web-addins

I'm developing an outlook add-in that's based on an existing web page I already have working (so mostly changing UI to fit the look and feel I want).
In the task-pane I open I have a "launch" button that I use to launch an external application.
The application already has a specific scheme registered and I can launch it when I get to the web page via the browser, but when I click through the task-pane nothing seems to happen.

Comment: By 'specific scheme' I presume instead of a https:// link you have something like appname:// that is registered in Windows?  I don't have this, but I'm wondering if you just need to put it in the AppDomains section including the scheme.

Comment: Will give it a try and update with results

Comment: worked this time. Thanks, do you want to convert to an answer so I can mark it as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please put the appname:// that is registered in Windows in the AppDomains section of the Outlook add-in manifest including the scheme and the domain, eg. appname://domain/